# How can I view <binary data> contents in Sql Data Tools Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, t-sql, binary-data, sql-data-tools

I have a problem viewing binary data field in SQL query results. The field values are exactly MD5 falues. Is there any features in SQL Data Tools to view this data?

Example is near https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B131IJR4wPHJZ2xzUE1UZVJac2s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add calculated field with code `CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), YourField, 2)` Try:

```
DECLARE @bin VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(35), @bin, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution works fine, but if there is any workaround offereв by VS interface?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to directly view binary data in VS